# Avoid .CONFIG files in Build task TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, msbuild-task

there's any property that I could set in MSBuild Argument in order to avoid config files in Build task?

Comment: Could you elaborate what's the meaning of avoid config files in Build task?

Comment: ok sorry , i mean , how no to publish .Config files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, you want to exclude .config file when you publish your web application.

If this is the case, instead of MSBuild argument, you have two options here:

1. In the .pubxml file, add an **ExcludeFilesFromDeployment** element in the **PropertyGroup** element. In this element, you can specify a single name, or you can specify multiple names delimited by semicolons (;), as shown in the following example:

   `<PropertyGroup">
     <ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>
       File1.aspx;File2.aspx
     </ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>
   </PropertyGroup>`
2. In project file, add an **ExcludeFromPackageFiles** element. For example let’s say that you have file named `Sample.Debug.js` which included in your web application but you want that file to be excluded from the created packages:

`<ItemGroup>
  <ExcludeFromPackageFiles Include="Sample.Debug.xml">
    <FromTarget>Project</FromTarget>
  </ExcludeFromPackageFiles>
</ItemGroup>`

Useful links:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942158(v=vs.110).aspx#can_i_exclude_specific_files_or_folders_from_deployment

http://sedodream.com/2010/05/01/WebDeploymentToolMSDeployBuildPackageIncludingExtraFilesOrExcludingSpecificFiles.aspx

Comment: Thanks @Cece Dong , that worked for me, also form TFS you could add a task in after MSBuild, "Delete files" task , and when i build from Visual Studio your answer is just perfect .